# Data representation/storage, xml / json or any other way

Tags: php, json, xml

I have to store some entities (amazon nodes), which have `id` and `name` properties
A node may or may not have sub nodes. 
Sub nodes too consists the id and name.

There's no limit to nesting. A sub node can have sub nodes and that sub node can have sub nodes of its own.

I chose to save this in json ( I am comfortable working with json )

e.g. 
A `History` node has subnodes `architecture` and `landmarks`.

Here's how I am storing this in json.

```
[
    {
            "id"   : "14278871",
            "name" : "History"
            "sub" : [
                {
                    "id"   : "173508",
                    "name" : "Architecture"

                },
                {
                    "id"   : "1000",
                    "name" : "Landmarks"
                }
            ]

        }
]
```

But it seems to be too much of data. Can someone provide me a better way ?

In xml, I came up with this,

```
<history id="14278871">
    <architecture id="173508"></architecture>
    <landmarks id="1000"></landmarks>
</history>
```

I am looking for better ways to store this data.

Ultimately, I need to use this data in php.

Comment: There are lots of different ways to do this. Arrays, objects, various linked lists... sounds like an interview question..

Comment: Its not an interview question. Ultimately I need to save into a file. I cannot store an array.

Comment: Either way it's not a big deal. You can use any of these methods. Objects / arrays can be serialized, JSON and XML can be compressed (if space is an issue). Im always a fan of building objects when I have to deal with lists like this.

Comment: an object just to store id/name ? Can you give an example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between your two formats isn't really the data structure, it's that you've switched the `name` fields from being data to being keys. The analogous JSON to your XML would be:

```
{ "history" :
   { "id": "14289981",
     "sub": {
        "architecture" : { "id" : "173508" },
        "landmarks" : { "id" : "1000" }
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: oh yes...and you think this is a good datatype to store this info ?

Comment: One data structure is about as good as another. It mostly depends on the application. The differences in readability may be a factor when debugging, but don't really affect the application itself.